# Question about Colab importing your own modules

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am relatively new to Colab & python, so I don't really know how to use it. I have git-cloned a GitHub repository onto my Colab notebook. There are some modules inside the GitHub folder that I have cloned that I need to import them into the notebook. For example, there is a utils and models module that I want to import. I ran the code:

> from models import *
> from utils import *

However, the Colab editor wrought the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'models'` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'`. This led me to realize that I haven't imported the modules from the Git Hub clone in Colab Files into Colab. I couldn't find an answer on StackOverflow, w3schools, or the Colab official sites so I
wrought my question here. If any of you have a link to a guide or a solution, please help me. Thank you!

[image: Here is a picture of the modules I cloned from the GitHub repository as well as my screen. Once again, Thank you for your time!]

Comment: Does `%cd pytorch_objectdetecttrack` work? Is jupyter magic, so you should run it in its own cell.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some of the Jupyter Notebook tricks worked. I used %cd pytorch_objectdetecttrack to get to the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert in Colab, but for Python `import` only works for Python modules.  So if there's a specific script you're trying to import, you will have to call it like `import folder.someModule`. The folder you're trying to access should go first, then the module name.

It's the same as saying `./folder/someModule.py`.

tl:dr; You have to specify the path to the module if it's not in the current working directory.